# Combine variables by adding rows

Tags: spss

I have different columns of contentious variables and each column represents a category. I would like to combine all columns into a single column by adding the appropriate number of rows and create a new column for the category name of each row using spss or excel.

This is what my data looks like now:
[image]

This is what I want to have:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple restructure, use `varstocases` like this:

```
varstocases make value  from A B C/index=category(value).
```